# weird behavior of regexp functions in oracle 19c

Tags: string, oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr, nls-sort

I am not an expert in regexp, but as default should be case sensitive on.
I try to figure it out why the regexp gives me the first 2 characters when the first one is capital

```
select regexp_substr('JohnFoo','[a-z]{2}') from dual;
```

the output is 'Jo'

if I tried this

```
select regexp_substr('JohnFoo','^[a-z]{2}') from dual;
```

the output is the same but it should recognize 2 non capital letters at the beginning so in this case no match

then I tried the same with all arguments

```
select regexp_substr('JohnFoo','[a-z]{2}',1,1,'c') from dual;
```

again the output is 'Jo' instrad of 'oh'

what am I doing wrong?this behavior is same fot substr ,replace as well. it seems to me like ignoring the capitals

Comment: I get "oh" in [this db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0eef7f0c00666d7ef267b01e892127c1)

Comment: Not a solution, but what happens if you try `'[^A-Z]{2}'`?

Comment: Review this page regarding NLS_SORT  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm

Answer (score 3):

You should first check the `NLS` setting in your session. The behaviour you expect is provided with the `BINARY` sort, which you probably do no have assigned.

Below a little example

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=BINARY;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY;

select regexp_substr('JohnFoo','[a-z]{2}') from dual;

RE
--
oh

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;

select regexp_substr('JohnFoo','[a-z]{2}') from dual;

RE
--
Jo
```

To get your actual session values use the query

```
select * from NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS 
where parameter in ('NLS_COMP','NLS_SORT');
```